# Linux: How to check if all cores in the guest VM are being utilized

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtual-machine, kvm

I have a Linux Guest VM with multiple vCPUs spawned using libvirt/qemu-kvm

Sometimes because of host kernel issues I suspect all the cores in the VM are not getting utilized correctly. I am looking for a programmatic way to check if the guest VM is getting its allocated number of vCPUs and the guest kernel scheduler is able to use both the cores.

Host kernel version: ubuntu 12.04.4 (3.11.0-20)
Guest kernel version: 2.6.27+

Answer (score 2):

You can grab the system load by `cat /proc/loadavg`  If you want the CPU %, see http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-find-out-linux-cpu-utilization.html